# Merge two Elasticsearch documents

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

I have a lot of pair documents that I want to merge in Elasticsearch, I mean :

> {id:3,message:"",churn_score:5.3}
>
> {id:3,message:"He is out",score:0}

What I want is to merge both documents into a single one :

> {id:3,message:"He is out",score:5.3}

Take the document with the numeric informations and to it the strings informations.

Should I use Spark API or can I do it directly with an Elasticsearch with cUrl in a .sh script for example ?

Thanks in advance,

Cya !